# PHP function which does syntax color parsing for multiple languages?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

I'm doing a PHP site which displays code examples in various languages (C#, PHP, Perl, Ruby, etc.). Are there any PHP functions which add syntax coloring for these and other languages?

If not, I would at least like to find that one built-in PHP function which does syntax coloring for PHP code, can't find it anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do the syntax coloration in the client side?

Use [prettify.js](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), its really versatile, Google Code and StackOverflow use it!

Check the [test page](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html) for the supported languages.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably be better off formatting it in javascript actually.  There are a few mature javascript syntax colors.

- [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)
- [google highlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/)
- [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

Answer (score 1):

For highlighting PHP use [highlight_string()](http://php.net/highlight_string). (This may work OK with other languages as well.)

**Edit:** This function requires that the string start with the PHP opening tag. What I did on my site to get around this was I passed something like `"<?php\n$code\n?>"` to the highlight_string() function and then used regex to strip out the starting and ending tags that I had added in. This method has worked pretty well for highlighting C/C++, Scheme, and Java (and PHP that doesn't have the `<?php ?>` tags.)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned Google prettify.js is really good, but if you want to do it on the server in PHP you could try looking at [Pear Text Highlighter](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Highlighter)